# Passar model genérico para controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Meu projeto segue o seguinte modelo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em meu `Controller` possuo o seguinte: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Notei que poderia estar usando esse `ActionResult` de forma dinâmica. Minha `view` é tipada.

Gostaria de saber se há como passar o tipo da minha `view` pro model ou então algum meio de receber dinamicamente o `model` em meu `controller`. Sendo no exemplo, meu `model` "GrupoHomogeneo".

Em resumo, minha intenção é passar o nome do `model` e de alguma forma, criar algo que retorna o model filtrado pelo nome em minha `ActionResult`, como no caso de um `System.Object`

"Exemplo" do que eu quero:

```
        var Nome = "GrupoHomogeneoEF";
        var bdModel = new (Nome)(contexto);
```

Comment: Qual o objetivo disso?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Reutilizar a mesma ActionResult para mais de um model

Comment: Tipado não dá. Os *Models* possuem um ancestral comum?

Comment: Sim sim. Apenas para constar, posso alterar a minha arquitetura para se adaptar a algum meio de conseguir fazer o que quero

Answer (score 4):

Ainda não entendi o que você quer fazer, mas a *View* aceita por padrão o seguinte:

```
@model dynamic
```

Ou seja, você pode sempre passar qualquer coisa.

Claro que isso tem consequências. Você precisa ficar conferindo se a propriedade de `Model` existe:

```
@if (Model.GetType().GetProperty("propriedade") != null) { ... }
```

Eu faria também um *Controller* genérico:

```
public abstract class Controller<T> : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
    where T: class, new() { ... }
```

E a *Action* `GrupoHomogeneo`:

```
public virtual ActionResult GrupoHomogeneo(T objeto, FormCollection collection) { ... }
```

Ou ainda, você pode definir um ancestral comum:

```
public abstract class ModelAncestralComum { ... }
```

E restringir o *Controller* genérico:

```
public abstract class Controller<T> : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
    where T: ModelAncestralComum, new() { ... }
```

Comment: Acredito que o Controller genérico me ajudaria. Tentei aqui mas obtenho erros, você poderia colocar a minha estrutura no seu exemplo?
Aplicando     `public abstract class WebController<T> : Controller
    where T: class, new() { Aplicacao.Core.RepositorioEF.Base.Repositorio<T>}` recebo mensagem "Invalid token '}' in class, struct, or interface member declaration"

Comment: Sim, edite sua pergunta colocando o código como texto que eu altero pra você.

Answer (score 2):

Bem, pelo que entendi você quer tornar seu controller generico e ter uma action generica, mas a view continuará a ser especializada.

Abaixo é uma sugestão bem direta ao seu ponto, mas teria N outras melhorias que poderiam ser feitas, você poderia [ler este artigo](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/01/28/Unit-of-Work-Repository-Pattern-in-MVC5-with-Fluent-NHibernate-and-Ninject.aspx) para ter mais informações.

```
public class GenericController<TObjeto, TRepositorio> : Controller
    where TObjeto : ObjetoBase, new()
    where TRepositorio : RepositorioEFBase, new()
{
    [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult AcaoGenerica(TObjeto objeto, FormCollection collection)
    {
        var repositorio = new RepositorioEFBase(contexto);
        ...
        return RedirectToAction(collection["ReturnView"], objeto);
    }
}

public class GrupoHomogeneoController : GenericController<GrupoHomogeneo, GrupoHomogeneoRepositorioEF>
{
}

public abstract class ObjetoBase
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
}

public class GrupoHomogeneo : ObjetoBase
{
    public string Campo1 {get; set;}
}

public abstract class RepositorioEFBase<TObjeto>
    where TObjeto : ObjetoBase, new()
{
    private DbContext _contexto;
    public RepositorioEFBase(DbContext contexto)
    {
            _contexto = contexto;
    }

    //utilize esse DbSet para os seus metodos genericos
    internal IDbSet<TObjeto> DbSet { get { return _contexto.Set<TObjeto>(); } }

    //metodos genericos do repositorio
}

public class GrupoHomogeneoRepositorioEF : RepositorioEFBase<GrupoHomogeneo>
{

}
```